# How to paste the content from dot . command

Tags: register

Given the word `foo` in a text, if I type `ciwbar<ESC>` while recording it as a macro in `w` register and then type in the command line
`:<C-r>w` it will brings me `:ciwbar^[`

However if i type `:<C-r>.` it will only brings me `bar`

But both commands, the `@w` and `dot`, are able to perform the **change inner word bar** in other parts of my text

Is there any way to get all the content from the dot as I got the `w` register? I would like to paste it and work to automate the last command in macros in some steps forward

Comment: You can get the last insertion using `@.`. But it is only a small part of the power of `.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said yourself there is a difference between a register like `@w` and `.` which is a command.

The `.` command is meant to repeat only simple, unit changes (as the doc says [`:h .`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#.): `Simple changes can be repeated with the "." command.`).

On the other hand, macros recorded in registers are meant to repeat more complex and longer changes (see help is at [`:h complex-repeat`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#complex-repeat)).

The behavior of the dot command is hard coded and does not use a register or a buffer which can be accessed by the user so there is no way to get what it will do as a vimscript string.